# Decompressing large files using multiple computers

Tags: zip, compression, bzip

We have to deal with extracting gzip/bzip files over the internet, sometimes they are way over multiple gigabytes (eg. 15gb [wiki dump](http://enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2)).

Is there a way that those can be extracted by multiple computers instead of by one? Perhaps reading the header plus the bytes between X and Y by each node in the cluster, writing it into a shared folder?

Or any other way that can accelerate that process?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a parallelized alternative to gzip/bzip?

In the scenario that you are using bzip, [pbzip2](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pbzip2) is a parallelized alternative using pthreads to speedup download. In addtion, a parallel alternative to gzip is [pgzip](https://github.com/klauspost/pgzip).

Comment: thanks but this only accelerates within one computer, what we want to achieve is enable clusters of nodes digesting one file.